# Install nuget package in a new project in solution, where package is already used for existing projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution, where I use Nuget for managing my packages.

Using Nuget, I have installed ie. entity framework in X projects in a solution. After, I have added a new project, and I want to install the entity framework in my new project.

However, when I open the nuget package manager, I cannot click install on existing packages I use. So how do I install the entity framework in my new projects?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console). Just select your project from the dropdown and run this command:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

You can also use [Manage NuGet Packages for Solution dialog](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/04/21/nuget-tip-3-manage-packages-at-the-solution-level), maybe that won't show those packages as installed.